# Server Error (500) in django deploying on heroky when debug=False

Tags: django, heroku

When I run with DEBUG=True everything works fine but when I set DEBUG = False I have only `Server Error 500`. I am using the latest Django version (3.x.x) and deploying my project to heroku. I have no idea why this is happening.

My settings.py file (some parts) as follows

```
import django_heroku
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['research-and-development.herokuapp.com',
                 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
# Application definition

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

# static and media files and urls set-up
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
# end of static and media files and url set-up

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail, e.g. by running `heroku logs`.

Comment: It did not show antghing extra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know whether it is the best answer or not. I have tried a lot of things. Eventually I removed ***django_heroku***. I followed the django heroku docs and my `settings.py` (some part) is as follows.

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['research-and-development1.herokuapp.com',
                 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0', ]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

DATABASES['default'].update(dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True))

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


# static and media files and urls set-up
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Before I push I have created psql database on heroku using the following command.
`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev` and I pushed with collected static files which are generated using `python manage.py collectstatic`. Have fun coding.